# Digitalocean, deploying jhipster app

Tags: server, jhipster, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy my *`jhipster`* app on `DigitalOcean`.

I have already created a *droplet*, connected to it with *ssh* and cloned the jhipster app from *`git`*. Now im having trouble with running the app on the server.

I can run the app on localhost, but I want to create remote access to it.
As i have never done it before I would like some help on how can I achiave that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://codespair.com/ansible-setup-digital-ocean
this article might help, i will try it tommorrow and report

Comment: What droplet are you using?  Some come pre-configured with `ufw` which blocks external access to ports

Comment: I chosen the default ubuntu, didnt add anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved my problem.

Didnt have to configure anything, just had to write in the url: ip adress of the virtual machine + : port number and it worked.
e.g:

```
http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8080
```